# Is there a statistical software package for the generalized conditional/multinomial logit model?

Tags: multinomial-logit, software, mlogit, clogit

I have a discrete choice model of moving from one state to the other, so alternatives=states. I have case-specific variables such as income, race, and gender. In addition, I have moving distance variable which varies over alternatives and cases because it depends on residence before moving (varying over cases) and the destination (varying over alternatives). The problem arises from this variable. I checked Matlab and Stata packages such as mlogit and clogit but realized that they do not allow variables which vary over both alternatives and cases. Is there any statistical software package which allows it?

Comment: Have a look at the `Apollo` package for `R`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own Bayesian model with extreme flexibility, which you could probably do in quite a few frameworks such as Stan (e.g. via `RStan` or `CmdStanR` in R or `pystan` in Python or the [various other interfaces](https://mc-stan.org/users/interfaces/) including for Stata and Matlab).

If you don't want to (and I think in this case you don't really need to) write your own Stan model code, then using a higher level package such as the [`brms`](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/) R package is a good option. One cool feature is that you could get the Stan code it creates and then use that in other software (e.g. Stata or Matlab, if those are your favorites since you mention them). It offers `categorical(link = "logit", refcat = NULL)` and `multinomial(link = "logit", refcat = NULL)` as distribution families, but I believe your intended model is different in that you want to give the model information on all the choices including the non-chosen ones, right? I believe there's some discussion on how to do this [here](https://github.com/paul-buerkner/brms/issues/560) and especially [here](https://solomonkurz.netlify.app/post/2021-11-17-conditional-logistic-models-with-brms-rough-draft/) (but the particular solution at the moment is not a [default family](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/reference/brmsfamily.html), yet, but can be used as described in that blogpost).

Answer (score 0):

https://www.elff.eu/software/mclogit/

The package `mclogit` for `R` serves the purpose to estimate conditional multinomial logit models